# SQL - Total Count

Tags: sql, amazon-ec2

Hi I am new to SQL and I was wondering if there is any way to just use a line from a larger JSON data which looks something like the following: It is part of the table named group

```
"instance":{
          "type":["m3.xlarge","m3.2xlarge","c3.2xlarge"]
          }
```

I want it to return only the id which has one instance type. For visual representation assume the table looks like the following

[group table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC8nC.png) 
i used something like the query below but it is incomplete

```
select id from group where config like '%type%' and deletedAt is null
```

Comment: does it shows any error

Comment: Why are you searching for `'%type%'`? That will return every row, because every row has the word `type` in the `config` column. Are you saying that you'd only want to return the 4th row, because it has only one type of instance? If so, you could use `not like '%,%'` because it doesn't contain a comma.

Comment: Thank you so much the not like parameter should work in this case. :)